# summing over $\sin(n\pi /2)$ and splitting sums into even and odd parts?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was looking for ways to evaluate an alternating series and then realized I had another problem I needed to work through first which was the presence of a $\sin(n\pi/2)$ which is a bit more complicated to substitute than $\cos(n\pi)$. I had an idea for simplifying my series by splitting it into even and odd parts as a way for rewriting $\sin(n\pi/2)$ and wanted to know others' thoughts on this approach. Details below:

$$\tag{1} u = \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} (1-2(-1)^n)\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})$$

By splitting up the sum,
$$\tag{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{p=2n}^\infty a_p + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{q=2n-1}^\infty a_q =$$.
Writing out the terms, it should look like $(a_2 + a_4 + a_6 +...) + (a_1 + a_3 + a_5 + ...)$. Using (2), I'll split u into it's even and odd parts

$$u = \frac{2}{\pi}\Big(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{p=2n}^\infty\frac{1+2}{q/2}*0+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{q = 2n-1}^\infty \frac{(1-2)}{(\frac{q+1}{2})}\sin(\frac{q\pi}{2})\Big)$$

simplifying this all down:

$$\tag{3} u = -\frac{2}{\pi} \sum_q^\infty \frac{(-1)^{\frac{q+1}{2}-1}}{q+1}$$

Where $(-1)^{\frac{q+1}{2}-1}$ (because of q = 2n-1) is effectively the same thing as if I had written $(-1)^{n-1}$. I feel like now I have a comfortable analog to $\cos(n\pi) = (-1)^n$. I guess I could also write $-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{2n-1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$

Are (2), and therefore (3), both correct? Or is there a better way for rewriting $\sin(n\pi/2)$?

---

Just as an aside, here is a test for rewriting $\sin(q\pi/2)$

$$q = 1: \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) = (-1)^{0} = 1 \\ q = 3: \sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}) = (-1)^{1} = -1 \\ q = 5:\sin(\frac{5\pi}{2}) = (-1)^{2} = 1$$

Comment: $\sin (n\pi /2) = {\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} ({\rm e}^{{\rm i}n\pi /2} )$

Comment: @Gary $$e^{in\pi/2} = \cos(n\pi/2) + i \sin(n\pi/2) \\ = i \sin(n\pi/2)$$ and $\Im(e^{in\pi/2} = \Im(i\sin(n\pi/2)) = \sin(n\pi/2)$. So yes that would work. and we would have $$u = \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-2(-1)^n}{n}\Im(e^{in\pi/2})$$

Comment: @Gary actually $\cos(n\pi/2) \ne 0$ for all n. It would be for all odd n and isin(n\pi/2) would be 0 for all even n. It's just $\Im(\cos(n\pi/2)+i\sin(n\pi/2)) = \sin(n\pi/2)$. Sorry for the mistake

Comment: Equation 2 splitting the odd and even terms is valid if the sum converges. Otherwise it may not.

Comment: @DhawalPatil Well by splitting here, the even terms are always zero, so I figured they wouldn't impact the convergence tests and I could split first and then test later. Perhaps I'm incorrect in thinking that though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two steps: first of all, if $n=2k$ is even, then $\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})=0$. So, replacing $n$ by $n=2k+1$, we have

$$
u 
= 
\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2k+1} (1-2(-1)^{2k+1})\sin(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2})
=
\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{3}{2k+1}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi)
$$

Since $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi)=(-1)^k$, we get

$$
u
=
\frac{6}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}
$$

Note: I am ignoring the problem of the convergence here. To make things rigorous, you should probably work with partial sums first.

Comment: Ah! So that's how you would properly rewrite it. As for the problem with convergence, I'm assuming the convergence test would simply be the alternating series tests which it looks fine in the form it is in here. $$1.lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2k+1} = 0 \\ 2.b_n \text{ decreases}$$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ResearcherR: The series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$ is only conditionally convergent, so one should be careful when rearranging, grouping, etc terms. Here, we are just removing $0$ terms so there should be no issue.